# browserAction.onClicked triggering after a listener is added

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a browserAction which I want to trigger only if a tab certain requirements are met.

```
var doStuff = function(tab) {
    ...    
};

if (trueCondition) {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "../icons/active.icon.png"});
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(doStuff).then(chrome.browserAction.onClicked.removeListener(doStuff));
} else {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "../icons/inactive.icon.png"});
};
```

I have also tried removing the listener as part of the if condition to no avail:

```
if (trueCondition) {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "../icons/active.icon.png"});
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(doStuff);
} else {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "../icons/inactive.icon.png"});
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.removeListener(doStuff);
};
```

This almost works, except when the condition is false it seems to store the events until the condition is true again and the listener is added once more, then it fires all of those events at once (3 or 4 times).

**Current scenario:**

- Activate tab where the browser action should trigger
- Listener is created with addListener
- Navigate to tab where the browser action *should not* trigger (browser action does nothing here)
- Navigate back to a tab where the action should trigger
- Actions carried out on the "non-functional" tabs all trigger in sequence (this is not desired behaviour)

Is there a way to essentially completely deactivate the listener so that when it is created again it is a "fresh" listener that doesn't have any previous events stored?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not need to remove listener. You can move the contidion into listener.

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab){
  if (trueCondition) doStuff(tab);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `doStuff()` function still triggers in this case. I can see that the else condition is met, as anything I put into there is carried out, but the listener still always activates if it has met a true condition once.